# Facebook api: get cover photo with app-scoped id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

guys!
Is there any possible way to get user cover photo using app-scoped id? Facebook graph-api accepts only actual facebook id.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get a cover photo without using an access token belonging to that application.

Only profile pictures are publicly accessible from an app scoped ID.

Comment: Ok, and how to achieve this with a token?

Comment: @LelkLelk you got the app scoped ID from an application, so you need an access token from that application.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. I mean, how to get a cover picture with token and app-scoped id?

Comment: does not work @phwd https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=4%2F%3Ffields%3Dcover